# How to show virtual keyboard on start Activity?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I want to show virtual keyboard as soon as activity is started, but unable to achieve it.. I am trying to set **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"** in manifest but it's not working for me..

It shouldn't be dismissed once i back press.

Is it possible to display virtual keyboard on our own layout???

Here is the part of manifest file

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FriendsList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".Places" />
</application>
```

Comment: can you please show your code in manifest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code its working

```
final TextView txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
       
       txtPassword.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0); 
        }
    },200);
```

Comment: Look recently i create code on 1st button click show virtual keyboard and on 2nd button click hide and it's working fine .

Comment: I don't want to show on button click, it has to be opened automatically once my activity is visible

Comment: Now its working, but is it possible to add keyboard on my own layout??